# What is the ASCII (Alt+number) for the square root symbol (√) in Windows?

Tags: ascii-art

How do I type the square root symbol (√) in Windows?

Comment: As a side note- that symbol, and the Alt-code to enter it have nothing to do with ASCII. ASCII only defines 128 symbols.

Comment: Well, really only 95 "printing" glyphs, counting the space. ASCII codes 32 through 126, inclusive. 0 through 31 are control  codes, and 127 is DEL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short it's ALT + 251 (note, no preceding zero)

Unicode it is U-221A

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm

√

If that doesn't work then:

```
Press and hold down the Alt key.
Press the + (plus) key on the numeric keypad.
Type the hexidecimal unicode value (221A).
Release the Alt key.
```

Comment: I am getting û for Alt 251

Comment: alt-251 is font dependent, so use the unicode sequence alt+221a as above - this will only work in unicode aware apps.  Note you can use charmap in most versions of Windows to work out either the alt sequence or alt-unicode sequence.

Comment: doesn't work. I am using an apple keyboard on a windows machine. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work for me

Comment: I am getting ¹ for Alt+251

Comment: Firefox did not work well with Alt+221A because when I pressed the A Key, it assumed I wanted to do Alt+A, and showed the "Advanced Search" panel instead.

Comment: Manufacturers of PCs have character sets in their hardware/firmware. These are called OEM code pages by windows. Windows also has a standard Latin character set for US/Can/UK... region users called Windows-1252, which it uses for most non-unicode programs. When you type ALT 251 ¹ you use the OEM set which can vary between each PC (Mine is code page 850). When you type ALT 0251 û, it uses the Windows-1252 character set.

Answer (score 2):

Open `regedit.exe`

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method`
and add a `string` or `REG_SZ` value
`EnableHexNumpad`. Set the value to `1`. Log out and log in.

Now you can use `ALT <numpad +> 221A`

**As for why your ALT codes don't work:**

Manufacturers of PCs have character sets in their hardware/firmware. These are called OEM code pages by Windows. Windows also has a standard Latin character set for english speaking regions called Windows-1252, which it uses for most non-unicode programs. When you type ALT 251 `¹` you use the OEM set which can vary between each PC (Mine is code page 850). When you type ALT 0251 `û`, it uses the Windows-1252 character set.

Some others were saying that `ALT 8730` `→`or `ALT 08730` `<substitute (SUB) character>` works but from my experience, any value above `ALT 255` or `ALT 0255` just gets converted back to a value between `ALT 0` and `ALT 255`.

Answer (score 1):

I used charmap and seeked to the position where the character U+221A is, clicked the buttons Select and Copy, then I pasted it where I wanted to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Alt 251 didn't work for me, nor did alt +... but alt 8730 did (0x221A in decimal), i.e. hold alt, type 8730 on the numeric pad, release alt.

√

Comment: →, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The actual (alt+X) codes didn't work, so I went into Symbols (using MS Word), used the Unicode (211A) to find squareRoot, and then added a shortcut to the symbol for easy access. I used (CTRL+{).