# Alt + 251 won't give me square root symbol. I get ¹ instead

Tags: keyboard

Sorry if my question is too noobish, but I can't get the square root symbol in my desktop pc using ALT + 251. When I type that key combination, it gives me `¹` instead. I have searched the internet, but I can't find any solution.

Probably relevant: I live in Colombia and just purchased this low budget second hand desktop. My keyboard language is Spanish(Colombia)
Operating system: Windows 8.1 Pro.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ASCII (Alt+number) for the square root symbol (√) in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/345543/what-is-the-ascii-altnumber-for-the-square-root-symbol-%e2%88%9a-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel (the desktop version)
Clock, Language, and Region.
Region.
Click on the Administrative tab on the top.
Under Language for non-Unicode programs , select the button Change system locale , then select English (US).
Restart your computer.